# How to convert "heading" rows into new columns

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I have data (imported imperfectly from a PDF) that has everything in a single column, with certain rows as descriptive headers. For example:

```
dfx <- data.frame(V1 = c("Box 1", "abcd10", "bcde15", "Box 2", "cdefg35", "jklm40", "nopq50", "rstu52"))

       V1
1   Box 1
2  abcd10
3  bcde15
4   Box 2
5 cdefg35
6  jklm40
7  nopq50
8  rstu52
```

I want to create a separate column where each observation takes on the value of the nearest heading above it. Like this:

```
       V1    v2
1  abcd10 Box 1
2  bcde15 Box 1
3 cdefg35 Box 2
4  jklm40 Box 2
5  nopq50 Box 2
6  rstu52 Box 2
```

Nothing I've tried has gotten me close. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do:

```
 indx <- grepl("^Box \\d+$",dfx$V1)
 transform(dfx,v2=V1[indx][cumsum(indx)])[!indx,]
       V1    v2
2  abcd10 Box 1
3  bcde15 Box 1
5 cdefg35 Box 2
6  jklm40 Box 2
7  nopq50 Box 2
8  rstu52 Box 2
```

Answer (score 1):

An idea via base R can be,

```
i1 <- grepl('Box', dfx$V1)
dfx$new <- with(dfx, ave(V1, cumsum(i1), FUN = function(i) i[1]))
subset(dfx, !i1)

#       V1   new
#2  abcd10 Box 1
#3  bcde15 Box 1
#5 cdefg35 Box 2
#6  jklm40 Box 2
#7  nopq50 Box 2
#8  rstu52 Box 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `V2` column which equals `V1` for the Box rows and `NA` for other rows and then use `na.locf0` to fill in the NAs.  Finally remove the `V1` Box rows.

```
library(zoo)

isBox <- grepl("Box", dfx$V1)
transform(dfx, V2 = na.locf0(replace(V1, !isBox, NA)))[ !isBox, ]
```

giving:

```
       V1    V2
2  abcd10 Box 1
3  bcde15 Box 1
5 cdefg35 Box 2
6  jklm40 Box 2
7  nopq50 Box 2
8  rstu52 Box 2
```